# ui5 TreeTable dynamic length

Tags: sapui5, treetable, sap-fiori

I'm using [sap.ui5.table.TreeTable](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.table.TreeTable.html) control in Fiori-like application.
For data binding I use annotations and tree work's fine.

My problem is to set Count of visible rows dynamically - it has to be changed after node is expanded / collapsed.

There is an event: toggleOpenState, but it's called before adding childrens.

How can I set this up ?

Thanks in advance,
Jakub

____________ EDIT _______________________

I have implemented toggleOpenState event:

```
toggleOpenState: function(oEvent) {
    console.log(oTable.getBinding("rows")._aRowIndexMap.length);
    console.log(oTable.getBinding("rows"));
}
```

when tree table is expanded from 3 to 8 rows in cosole there is:

[image]

I need to return 8, but I don't know how.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: I used code like here (point 2): http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2015/10/23/treetable-odata-binding. I can't find proper event to call setVisibleRowCount(rowsAfterExpand)

Answer (score 0):

Please share some code and we can help further...
In general just get the model of the table and then call get data method.
like

var data = this.getView().getModel("name of model").getData()

or if multiple models on the same view then

var data = this.getView().byId("tableid").getModel().getData();

and then play with data variable which will contain data from that model.